# having trouble loading data into two dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to load data into two dimensional array.
my code is as

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] datas=null;

        datas = new String[4];

        datas[0] = "abc,def,ghi";
        datas[1] = "1,2,3";
        datas[2] = "abc,def,ghi";
        datas[3] = "1,2,3";

        int cols = datas.length;
        int rows = datas[1].split(",").length;
        System.out.println("rows="+rows+" and cols="+cols);


        String[][] table_data= new String[cols][rows];
        for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("came for " + i);
            table_data[cols] = datas[i].split(",");
        }

        System.out.println("Table Datas = " + Arrays.deepToString(table_data));

    }
}
```

but i am getting index out of bound exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:24)
```

i tried changing declaration to

```
String[][] table_data= new String[cols+1][rows+1];
```

it show me output as

```
rows=3 and cols=4
came for 0
came for 1
came for 2
came for 3
Table Datas = [[null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null], [1, 2, 3]]
```

but that is not the output i want. any help would be so great full.

Comment: `table_data[cols]` will be out of bounds since indices are from 0 to cols-1 (and when you increase the size of `table_data` you always write to the same index). I guess you mean `table_data[i]` instead. Btw, looking at the stacktrace (e.g. MyClass.java line 24) and if needed using a debugger should show that quite fast.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you have to change `table_data[row]` with `table[i]`.

```
for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
     System.out.println("came for " + i);
     table_data[i] = datas[i].split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
table_data[cols-1] = datas[i].split(",");
```

because you set the array with 4 columns :

```
String[][] table_data= new String[cols][rows];
```

where `cols = 4`, and then you try to edit the index 4, which is in fact the 5th element (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and doesn not exist :

```
table_data[cols] = datas[i].split(",");
```

But since this assignement occurs in a loop with no further code  :

```
for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
{
    System.out.println("came for " + i);
    table_data[cols] = datas[i].split(",");
}
```

, it doesn't make sense anyway. As another aswerer wrote, you probably wanted to write :

```
for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
{
    System.out.println("came for " + i);
    table_data[i] = datas[i].split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always writing to the last element of the array. You should use `table_data[i]` instead of `table_data[cols]`.